# How to access array elements with sqlalchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a db column that contains comma separated values (for example "happiness,destroy,decoration"). I can query

```py
query = select(
    func.string_to_array(comma_column, ",")
)
```

to split the values into an array like `[happiness, destroy, decoration]`.

I want to select the third one, but if I try to write

```py
query = select(
    func.string_to_array(comma_column, ",")[2]
)
```

I get `NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression`.

Is there a way to make the getitem work or is there some other function that I can use with the postgresql backend?